# Drag one object at a time animating elements with react-spring usesprings hook

Tags: reactjs, react-three-fiber

I am attempting to use react-spring's useSprings to enable users to drag one object at a time.
but all object start dragging.

I am expecting to drag one object at a time. and that will not effect other object.

```
const objs= [
        {"id":1005420887,"Position":[0, 0 , 0]},
        {"id":1005420888,"Position":[0, -0.76 , 0]}
    ]

const [ springs, api ] = useSprings(objs.length, i=> ({
        position:  objs[i].Position,
        scale: 1,
        rotation: [0, 0, 0],
        config: {friction: 10}
        
    }) )

const bind = useDrag(
        ({args: [originalIndex], active, movement: [x, y, z], timeStamp, event}) => {
            console.log('spring',springs[0].position.toJSON());
            console.log('spring1',springs[1].position.toJSON());
            if (active) {
                Ppos
                event.ray.intersectPlane(props.floorPlane, planeIntersectPoint);
                setPPos(prevState => ({
                    ...prevState,
                    [originalIndex]: [planeIntersectPoint.x, 0, planeIntersectPoint.z]
                }))
              } 

            props.setIsDragging(active);
            console.log( "Use Drag " + [y / aspect, x / aspect, 0]);

            api.start({
                position: springs[originalIndex].position.toJSON(),
                //position: pos,
                scale: active ? 1 : 1,
            });
            return timeStamp;
        }
    );


 {springs.map((spring, i) => {
                    return (
                        <animated.mesh {...bind(i)}>
                            <Box key={i} position={spring.position.toJSON()} args={[1, 0.1, 0]} color={'red'}>
                               
                            </Box>
                        </animated.mesh>
                    )
                })}
```